# CodeIgniter set_select not repopulating after post

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

I've got a select box created in CodeIgniter. When I pull the value out of the databse, the form is populated no problem. But after I submit the form, the select box is reset to zero.

Here is my code:

```
<select name="week[tuesday][startam]" id="" class="small">
    <?php for( $i = 0; $i < 24; $i=$i + 0.25 ):?>
           <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"<?php echo set_select('week[tuesday][startam]', $i, ($i==(float)$model_week['tuesday']['startam'])); ?>><?php printf('%02d:%02d', floor($i), ( ($i-floor($i))*60 ) ); ?></option>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</select>
```

I wondered if the problem was that `set_select()` is comparing the `$_POST[week][tuesday][startam]` value (which is a string) to `$i` (which is a float). But casting `$i` to a string doesn't seem to make a difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your controller? at least the form verification part.

Comment: I think you're on to something: I don't think I've added them to the rules array - will add and re-test.

Comment: Added to the validation rules now, and it seems to work fine. Problem solved. Thanks for the suggestion, @chaft.

Comment: @JasonC can we see? I'm _very_ curious as to how form_validation solved this issue... I may have a grave misunderstanding of what is going on and would appreciate learning something.

Comment: @stormdrain sure - I can't post an answer yet (answer my own question) because my rep isn't high enough. I'll post here in the mean-time:

I added them to the rule set and now everything works as expected. So, for the above code I posted I have:

    `$validation_rules = array(
        array(
            'field' => 'week[tuesday][startam]',
            'label' => 'Tuesday morning start',
            'rules' => 'trim'
        )
    )
    $this->form_validation->set_rules( $validation_rules );
    $is_valid = $this->form_validation->run();`

Comment: OK, all that does is trim the `week['tuesday']['startam']` input... it has NOTHING to do with which option is selected after the form submission.

Comment: @stormdrain you have to use validation rules to repopulate form fields so `set_something` can work. [link](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#repopulating) not very obvious but stil. You can read about it more here: [link](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/190817/#901050)

Comment: OK, that makes sense. However, it does nothing for set_select; it works with set_value. My insistence was based on not being able to get set_select to behave as OP wanted. Thanks.

Comment: @stormdrain my code above does only trim the entry, yes, but the fact that I've added it to the form validation rules means that my code as above in the main post works. In fact, I could have used `'rules' => ''` which obviously does nothing, and yet that's all I needed to get the thing to work.

Comment: @JasonC If you say so... I don't see how only adding form_validation could have fixed your issue, but I'll take your word for it. I do see that it matters for repopulating when using set_value, but not set_select... At least it's working now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @chaft, I looked again at my validation rules and found the fields I was concerned about missing. I added them to the rule set and now everything works as expected. So, for the above code I posted I have:

```
$validation_rules = array(
    array(
        'field' => 'week[tuesday][startam]',
        'label' => 'Tuesday morning start',
        'rules' => 'trim'
    )
)
$this->form_validation->set_rules( $validation_rules );
$is_valid = $this->form_validation->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be because after you submit, there is no beginning value for $model_week['tuesday']['startam'] and therefore no set_select has the third param set to TRUE

Check for $_POST and if set, set the value to the posted value;

```
if($_POST){
    $model_week['tuesday']['startam']=$_POST['week']['tuesday']['startam'];
}else{
    $model_week['tuesday']['startam']=5;//or initial db value
}
```

---

```
    <select name="week[tuesday][startam]" id="" class="small">
        <?php for( $i = 0; $i < 24; $i=$i + 0.25 ):?>
               <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"<?php echo set_select('week[tuesday][startam]', $i, "FALSE"); ?>><?php printf('%02d:%02d', floor($i), ( ($i-floor($i))*60 ) ); ?></option>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </select>
```

^ see if you can get that code to ever have a selected value other than 00:00

You can't. Because you will never have an option selected without 1 set_selected having the third paramater as TRUE, whether on the default page load or after a form submission.

---

Heres a quick and dirty example:

```
public function index(){
    if($_POST){
        $model_week['tuesday']['startam']=$_POST['week']['tuesday']['startam'];
    }else{
        $model_week['tuesday']['startam']=5;//would be the default value
    }
?>
<form action="" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <select name="week[tuesday][startam]" id="" class="small">
        <?php for( $i = 0; $i < 24; $i=$i + 0.25 ):?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"
                <?php echo set_select('week[tuesday][startam]', $i, ($i==(float)$model_week['tuesday']['startam'])); ?>>
                <?php printf('%02d:%02d', floor($i), ( ($i-floor($i))*60 ) ); ?>
            </option>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="some_name" value="rrrr" id="some_name">
    </form>
<?php
}
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be set to true, because that third parameter is only used when *not* submitting. After you submit, it doesn't matter what the default value is because you're only trying to populate the form with the values just submitted, not the defaults.

Comment: So how do you populate the form with the submitted values then? Magic? No, you have one of the option values set to SELECTED with the value submitted! set_selected isn't only for default values, you use it to set the value you want selected.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but the third parameter you're talking about is only used to set the default value when **not** submitting. The form helper sets the `SELECTED` based on what you've just submitted by comparing the postdata to the second parameter of `set_select()`. The third parameter is optional and the helper still works _without_ using magic.

Comment: I updated the answer with an example controller function. What I am saying is that without any of the options' set_select having the third parameter set to TRUE, you absolutely will not have an option selected. It's simple: if you want to have an option selected after submit, one of those options has to have the TRUE. Make a dummy function with the last bit of code I put, go to the page, submit, and you will see the submitted value selected.

Comment: you don't have to use the third parameter at all to get the helper to work after form submission. So it works fine after submission even if all the third parameters are false.

Comment: Can you show me? I've been testing for a few minutes now and I have yet to find a way to have an option selected without a TRUE in set_select. If they are empty or all set to FALSE (which would have been the case with the question you posed as the default value would have been empty), 00:00 is selected (which was also the issue you reported having).

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I *could not* get it to behave that way... And the CI forum posts I saw said that form_validation repopulation was for set_value only and didn't work with set_select. TIL!

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem, like what JasonC did, validating the form works. I had 2 fields but only 1 was properly set upon posting. Didn't occur to me that form validation would cause such a problem. Thanks to chaft!